# Partial letters for auto complete in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, autocomplete, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio (2012, 2015) to use a "partial" auto complete similar to Intellij?

For example, when using `WebClient` I want to be able to just type `webClient.dd` and it should show `DownloadData()` and `webclient.dda` would show `DownloadDataAsync()`.